# Prevent duplicate class generation (__1) with jsonschema2pojo

Tags: java, json, jsonschema2pojo

I have some json schema that I try to convert to pojo classes using [jsonschema2pojo](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo).
Unfortunately, I get some duplicated classes generated with an additional `__1` postfix on the classname.

You can test this at https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/.
Add this example and hit `Preview`:

```js
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "something": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {}
    },
    "other": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "physical": {
          "$ref": "#/properties/something"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get the classes `Something` and `Something__1`. They have the same code (except the class name).
I found other questions, where someone commented that one can change some `ObjectRule` and `RuleFactory`, but I don't want to patch the library.

Is there something with my schema or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

jung,

The below code might be working for you, I am facing the same issue for a week and walked through the lots of docs and references available.

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
        "other": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "physical": {
          "existingJavaType":"com.example.Something" // package name with class name
        }
      }
    },
    "something": {
      "type": "object"
    }

  }
}
```

[Refer this](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/issues/828#issuecomment-396077732)

Comment: Looks like a hack to me, and can only be applied if the schema is only used for Java and it's your own schema, but it's a possible solution.